# FAQ: What are the attributes of a good question?

Tags: discussion, faq, asking-questions

What does a good Skeptics.SE question look like? What are the qualities that a perfect Skeptics.SE question would have?

**Ground rules for answering this meta-question:**

- One quality per answer
- Provide a brief explanation of why it is important.
- Use the comments for discussion.
- If you don't agree, downvote the attribute. If you agree, upvote.

Related Question: [What are the attributes of a good **answer**](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-answer)?

Answer (score 13):

#### Write for an international audience.

This is not the key point of a good question, but after fulfilling the main requirements, a question should be international.

Citing US television series, discussing laws of the USA,  US-centric politics or naming locally-known celebrities is not very inviting for everybody else. At least, introduce them, explain in short words what it is about (Snopes) - and maybe link to online sources.

I don't know how well known the metric system is in the US. In the 70s, I heard it was internationally accepted standard, but it seems, it isn't.

Comment: The last paragraph (about the metric system) seems completely disrelated to the rest of this answer.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10):

**Questions should have references to show that they are notable.**

References also help clarify the theory that is being investigated.

Answer inspired by:

- [When in doubt ask for a citation](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/when-in-doubt-ask-for-a-citation/879#879)
- [How notable does a claim have to be?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-notable-does-a-claim-have-to-be-for-questions-about-it-to-be-considered-on-to)
- [My friends says...](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/796/my-friend-says)

Answer (score 9):

**Ensure your question is open to answers from both sides** - even if you think you know what the right answer should be.

Leading words and other forms of bias should be removed.

Answer inspired by:

- ["Untruthable" questions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/777/untruthable-questions)
- [Use of "Really" in questions](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/445/is-there-really-a-reason-why-so-many-questions-really-need-to-include-the-wo)

Answer (score 8):

**Questions must be answerable.**

There are various kinds of question which are not unanswerable: they cannot create the [high quality answers](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/868) which we require on this site.

Kinds of questions which are **NOT answerable** include:

- What individuals believe or are motivated by

  For example, we cannot know whether Hitler was really a Christian. We can quote passages where he claimed to be a Christian, but we can never know what he truly believed.
- Imprecise questions

  For example, "Is public transport better than private vehicles?" It may be that one is better than the other in some ways but not in others. To be complete an answer would need to analyse all the different ways. Questions must be precise, so that answers too can be precise.
- Questions which call for personal experiences

  For example, "What are your favourite sceptical questions?" and "Do you find that being sceptical helps you?"
- Questions about science

  For example "How do magnets work?"
  This forum is not for asking question about "how" and "why". Instead, Sceptics is for questioning whether claims are even true.
  Other questions about science belong on [other StackExchange forums](http://stackexchange.com/sites), for example the [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) and the [Fitness and Nutrition](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/) forums.
- Questions about scepticism

  For example, "What is scepticism?" and "What's the best way to teach my child to be sceptical about advertising?"
- Political questions, about values

  For example, "Should marijuana be legalised? (or euthanasia)", or "Should taxes be lowered?" These questions are not precise (there are too many different arguments, for and against) and subjective (the answer depends on what value you personally attach to each argument).

  You can however question a specific claim which has political significance (for example, "Would legalising drugs reduce crime?").

Comment: "Would legalising drugs reduce crime?" is not objectively answerable.  We can only objectively look at correlations for situations where drugs were legalised and what happened to crime rates after that (causation is more difficult to establish, of course).

Answer (score 7):

**Any unclear terms and assumptions are explained.**

If you don't know how to define a term, ask the answerer to provide the definition they are using.

Answer inspired by:

- [How pedantic should we be?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/859/how-pedantic-should-we-be)
- [Should we ask questions that don't have answer](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175/should-we-ask-questions-that-dont-have-answers)

Comment: I have something to add, but can't decide if this should be an edit or a new answer. Terminology should be as clear and precise as possible. Consider if there is an alternative interpretation for any terms. If a term could be interpreted more broadly than you intend, then add a qualifier to make it more specific.

Answer (score 7):

**The question should be phrased using respectful language.**

While there are no taboo topics here, all claims (and especially potentially offensive claims such as claims about [race](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/850/questions-on-black-people-or-other-colour-should-be-allowed) or [porn](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264/the-porn-question)) must be asked about in respectful manners. It is hard to know what people find offensive, but it's a lot easier for a reader to understand if the language of the question is respectful.

Profanities in answers and questions [will be removed](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/613/policy-on-profanity). They are not allowed here.

Some current examples:

- [Is it true that black people, on average, can jump higher than white people?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1456/is-it-true-that-black-people-on-average-can-jump-higher-than-white-people)
- [VHS vs Betamax: How influential was the pornography industry in the format war?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/vhs-vs-betamax-how-influential-was-the-pornography-industry-in-the-format-war)

Answer (score 5):

**Questions should not be about what individuals believed or were motivated by.**

Simply put, [such questions cannot be meaningfully answered.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/politics-beliefs-and-motivations-questions-should-not-be-allowed-here)

For example, we cannot know whether Hitler was *really* a Christian. We can quote passages where he claimed to be a Christian, but we can never know what he truly believed.

Comment: So, questions like "Did JFK want to put nuclear weapons on the moon?" would be off-topic, but "Were there plans under JFK to put nuclear weapons on the moon?" would be okay?

Comment: Under *this* rule, yes. You could produce signed copies of the plans to answer the second question, but the first question would still be unknown - JFK may have had the plans produced but not wanted to follow them.

Comment: Your example isn't good. If Hitler was baptised can be investigated, did he pay church taxes, did he marry in front of a priest? If 'Christian' is a meaningful word, there must be some attributes, describing, what a Christian is, and what he is not.

Comment: @user unknown, I think the definition of Christian that is intended here is approximately "a believer in Jesus Christ and his teachings" - i.e. focussed on his belief, not his actions.

Comment: Afaik, muslims believe in Jesus Christ too, so it can't be a useful distinction.

Comment: I included the word "approximately" to cover that; I considered adding something about acknowledging as a messiah, but I decided not to get too off-topic. I think the original answer's meaning is still clear to the "person-in-the-street".

Comment: I think this should be merged into a more general-but-concrete category which [lists all the negatives/prohibitions in one place](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/978#978).

Comment: I'm am unsure: I like that this is individually linkable, and votable to show some consensus. I am also trying to understand how this "multiple answer" entry will look when we get to appointing it with official FAQ-tag status. Happy to discuss in chat, if you like.

Comment: [See in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1255716#1255716) then.