# What are all the different FAQs and Help pages?

Tags: discussion, faq

There are a number of different FAQ pages provided by the StackExchange software that drives this site.

How do they all fit together? How do I get changes made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a brief summary of what I learnt. It isn't something people need to know to use the site; it is just for those that are interested in how the site is organised.

**Skeptics.SE Site Help Center**

At the top of Skeptics.SE page, (i.e. the main page) there is a [help](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help) link to the Help Center. This describes the basics of how to ask questions, vote, etc. Most users probably won't read the fine manual, but if they do, this is the one they will read first.

(This *used* to be known as the FAQ, which caused some confusion. It now has a better name.)

The **first** item in the Help Center is "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)". It is about the scope of Skeptics.SE. It is under the control of our community. (Want to change it? Ask a question here, [like this one](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/948/improving-the-faq)).

The rest of the Help Center is [common to all StackExchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95160/experimental-stack-exchange-faq-improvement-project). It is under active development, but we (i.e. the skeptics) have [limited control](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95160/experimental-stack-exchange-faq-improvement-project/95818#95818) over the text.

**Meta.Skeptics.SE Site FAQ**

At the top of *Meta*.Skeptics.SE page (i.e. where you are now), there is a link to an equivalent [Help Center](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) for Meta. Same idea. The text is common to all meta sites.

There is a special feature that the first time you click on it, it takes you to a ["What is Meta?"](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) sub-page of the Help Center.

**Common StackExchange FAQ**

If you want to know *more* about StackExchange software, there is a common [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) over on Meta.StackOverflow. It's probably a little too obscure to find for new users, but it is a good resource for experience users to be able to give official answers to any detailed questions about the software that arise, such as here in Meta.Skeptics.

If you have a question that isn't answered there, you can ask it here. If we can't answer it locally, we'll help you get it escalated.

**Community Standards**

With the exception of that one scope question, the above resources are all about the software and how to use it, and **not** about our own Skeptics.SE community-imposed standards.

Those standards are debated here on Meta.Skeptics. If you want to see change, ask a question here, and be prepared to be persuasive.

**Skeptics Community FAQ Questions**

Some meta-questions will be promoted by the moderators. The questions and an approved answer will be cleaned up and be given a special tag [faq](/questions/tagged/faq).

These questions will be useful for citing when other people have questions or confusion about how our community works. They can also be found by searching for [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) on the meta-site.

If you would like a new Skeptics Community FAQ question, you should post a question here with the tag [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq). When consensus is reached, a moderator will tidy up the question, and the official answer, deleting any extraneous answers and discussion that will confuse a new user reading it. **Note:** Please be aware that your alternative answers and discussion on a [proposed-faq](/questions/tagged/proposed-faq) question will be short-lived. Once they have done their purpose in shaping the final text, it will be deleted.