# I don't think my (revised) answer should have been deleted

Tags: discussion

I'd first like to point out that I have > 1000pts on stackoverflow.com and nearly the same on serverfault - so I'm not a general forum troublemaker.

I wrote an answer to the question "[Is Europe on the verge of a financial crisis?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/is-europe-on-the-verge-of-a-financial-crisis)", which I believe answered at least the title of the original question. This was then removed with a comment that it didn't answer the question. I then made some edits and made a request for it to be reconsidered. This was also rejected on the same grounds. I then re-read the original question and realised that what the poster was asking was in fact slightly different to its title. I then realised that what I had written could act as supporting arguments to a concluding paragraph, such that the entirety of my answer, addressed both the title and the body of the original posters question. Unfortunately this was deleted too, with an accusation that it had no references, which actually it did have. I don't see why my mkIII answer should be deleted. And if it should then I'd like a proper explanation so that I can be a better contributor to this site.

P.S. my mkIII answer was submitted as a separate answer rather than an edit to the existing answer. I know this was probably against convention. - Guilty as charged.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, [welcome to the site](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). We are a bit different from the other SE sites you are more familiar with, and I am sure this is the source of the confusion.

Your answer starts with the following:

> Very possibly. And not just Europe...

The main body of the answer — 7 paragraphs — talks about the banking system, reserves and leverage. Unfortunately, it does not really specifically address Europe. More in particular, it does not touch the *current* European situation, either.

At the end, you've added an extra paragraph which actually answers the question:

> So to answer your question, the indicator to look at is the (true) leverage of the banks. I say true because I mean the ratio of bank loans to the true value of the banks capital assets when the probability of defaults is properly factored in.

So, all in all, the vast majority of your answer does not address the claim in any specific way, and only a paragraph tries to answer the question — but does not actually succeed. This is a pretty wide question, and there are no less than 8 claims in it. You do not really address any of them.

The problems that you should be fixing are:

1. We want to *see the facts behind the claims*. What facts are you providing? Can you provide hard, solid references that we can find convincing? Multiple serious, verifiable, peer-reviewed studies, for example?
2. Why is the indicator to look at the leverage of the banks? If the banks had less leverage would it be better? For whom (companies, middle class, PIIGS, etc.)? Where is the evidence here?
3. You need to address the claims in the question and look/provide the facts. At the moment you seem to substantially ignore them.
4. Good answers should look at the facts *first* and come to a thesis *second*. You seem to have formed an opinion *first*. Go back to the beginning. Try to find facts first and compose an answer based on them. If the facts do not support your current idea on the matter, it's not appropriate here.

Comment: I take all of your points. But I still think my answer has some validity and should not have been removed. The questioner will not get a better answer and the moderator has deprived the questioner of some useful information.

Comment: When your answer was deleted it was completely off topic. You have merely added 3 lines. The purpose of this site is to present facts, not speculation. We try to protect the signal to noise ratio of the former vs the latter.

Comment: "completely off topic" - nonsense - it answered the title of the original question. It quite naturally only required a small modification to answer the body of the question.

Comment: Did the question have a lot of downvotes? If not maybe the community should have a chance to judge the answer.

Comment: The community, or more precisely 10k users, can alreadty see them (it's two). They can also undelete if they so choose.

Comment: Having thought about it more, I have to say that I find your explanation mostly unfounded. The added-last-paragraph is a direct consequence of everything that came before. It would make no sense on its own. The bulk of my answer is based on the facts set out in the reference I gave. I also note that you are not actually disputing either my logic or the facts in my answer.