# Why are so few questions left open?

Tags: discussion, politics

Only two of the last twelve questions remained open on this StackExchange.

Why are so many held? Seems like they're closed when people here don't know how to answer the question (like the vaccine one) rather than just waiting for a person with the right expertise who understands the question to answer it.

Comment: There are very specific guidelines for questions here, and ones that don't meet those (like https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26709/why-are-only-2-of-last-twelve-questions-open), get closed eventually.

Comment: For instance, this particular question is likely to get put on hold as well, or even moved to meta.skeptics.se...

Comment: You're asking about 10 different questions, which would make it tedious to answer in any detail.

Answer (score 11):

> why are only 2 of last twelve questions open?

Every question put on hold has a close reason displayed in yellow. Generally, they also have comments because the generic close reasons can be unclear.

So, you can see for yourself why each one is closed.

> Seems like they're closed when people here don't know how to answer the question

That's not a close reason; none were closed for that reason. (Although, a question that cannot be answered with scientific skepticism, or is better answered on a site with subject matter experts, might be closed as off-topic - e.g. [this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26694/can-a-website-see-how-you-got-to-the-site-by-what-search-term-or-the-last-webs))

> like the vaccine one

The [vaccine question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/26684/do-the-risks-of-measles-vaccinations-outweigh-the-risks-of-non-vaccination) didn't have a notable claim. It was a rather confusing question, and you will notice there has been some effort to work out how to best re-word it, both in the comments and [in a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20939/formulating-the-measles-vaccine-question).

Arguably, it isn't a *lack* of expertise, but a *wealth* of expertise that is slowing this one down, as people dig through the anti-vax position (not held by the OP!), trying to find a clear claim that can be supported or disproved. Knocking down a strawman is of little value.

I recommend reading the [Welcome to Skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) meta-question, which is widely linked in the comments on posts by new users.