# Is "belief in the claim" part of notability time constrained?

Tags: discussion, notability, scope

I was reading a Meta question about "Flat Earth" question, and the answers ([at least one](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3292/1044)) seem to be predicated on a time constraint:

> Several people **believe** <sup>(note **present** tense)</sup> the claim

I think it is obvious that plenty of people believed the Flat Earth claim in the past<sup>[citation needed]</sup>.

As such, should the assertion (let's assume it's true) that not enough people believe such a claim **now** be enough to decline notability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: a notable claim must have believers in the present. It has to be an actual problem that people face.

These are our current guidelines:

- [A claim is 'notable' when a significant number of people believe it is true.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim)
- [With no burden of proof on the asker that someone else believes the claim they're asking you to fact-check, you risk losing your specialty...](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable)
- [[A question] provides evidence that many people believe it, so it is worth lifting a finger to research it, in an effort to reduce (not increase) the spurious claims spread over the Internet.](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/what-is-minimum-notability-of-claims-for-this-site)

All these use the present tense and this is not casual, it's a meaningful choice. The [reason](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is that on *any* Stack Exchange site

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Addressing what people believed in the past, but *don't believe anymore* is, by definition, not helping anyone today.