# Are men more likely to delete a post because a woman answered?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed I always get downvoted by men, and helped/answered by women. 
Why are men so skeptical of women's intelligence on this forum?

We don't even have the "Tag" EQUALITY on here yet.

Answer (score 20):

*I suspect you are not entirely genuine in your motives, but I am answering so other people reading can see that there is nothing behind this claim.*

- You have answered a total of two questions on this site. Neither followed the community standards. I invite you to read the [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) link to better understand what makes a good answer.
- You don't know who downvoted you, so you don't know whether it is men. You have made up that claim.
- Both times, I was the only one to respond. I would characterise that as helping you. You made up the claim that only women help you.
- Your profile, picture and username do not reveal your gender. So your implied claim that your answers were deleted because you are a woman is ridiculous.
- It isn't clear why a tag of "equality" is necessary or is inevitable. That seems to be a non-sequitur.

There *is* a gender-imbalance on Skeptics.SE (at least based on the last time I went through the top 100 users - at least a couple of years ago - and counted the people who had gendered profiles, which is obviously an unreliable sampling method.)

I believe there *is* a problem in the general Skeptics community of women not being treated with equal respect and having their intelligence unfairly questioned.

If people have serious concerns about the gender issues on Skeptics.SE, and especially ways we can help fix them, I would love to hear them. This question, however, isn't helping the conversation.

Comment: There's plenty of woman who have male personas on the Internet but I suspect not the reverse. I always wondered the % of women Internet users who avoid being female online.

Comment: @SamIAm: Yes, and I suspect a higher percentage of women use gender-neutral profiles than men. Plus, modelling gender as a binary leads to more problems. Trying to work out the gender balance just based on what we can tell from profiles is an unreliable sampling method. That said, the lack of balance here is so strong, I assume it outweighs such considerations - there is little chance that the number of women equal the number of men, even with such large error bars in our measurements.

Comment: I didn't actually think there was...

Comment: @SamIAm, sorry to be unclear. I didn't mean to imply that I thought that. I don't think we are disagreeing at all.

Comment: FWIW, [this member of Biology SE](http://biology.stackexchange.com/users/9943/aliced) has a female sounding username but is in fact male. I have seen him being belittled for being female more than once in the questions/answers.

Comment: @MarchHo: I'd encourage flagging such behaviour on any SO site. I don't think we see it much here, but if we did, I would want us (the community) to stop any participants in that behaviour quickly.

Comment: Yup, I did that, but my point was that the reverse does exist, and shows how bad the situation is.

Comment: Ummm... how do you know if he's adopting a female persona or if Alice is his given name? [Man Named Kim Adds 'Mr.' to Resume, Lands Job](http://abcnews.go.com/blogs/business/2013/07/man-named-kim-adds-mr-to-resume-lands-job/). The whole idea of adopting a male persona online is to take away from your femaleness is to be taken seriously and/or avoid harassment. Also very common with pen names for authors.

Comment: @SamIAm: "There's plenty of woman who have male personas on the Internet but I suspect not the reverse." -- I think it depends a lot on which community you're talking about. At least in [some places on the Internet](http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2014/05/13/world_of_warcraft_gender_switching_why_men_choose_female_avatars.html) men tend to use female personas.

Comment: @Flimzy Fascinating. thanks for the link.

Comment: @SamIAm that link is wildly inaccurate (e.g. when it claims that wow models are made by males for males). wow has plenty of non-stereotyped characters.

Comment: Let's take it to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30364/discussion-on-answer-by-oddthinking-are-men-more-likely-to-delete-a-post-because).