# Answer stated question but deleted by mod

Tags: discussion

My question was deleted by a mod for not answering the *primary* question.

[Access to water](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/40629/does-anybody-spend-6-hours-each-day-just-to-get-water/40635?noredirect=1#comment170932_40635)

It is the last question and has a question mark.  How is it not a valid answer to address that point?

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the question we can see several parts pointing to the primary question:

The title reads:

> Does anybody spend 6 hours each day just to get water?

**The answer didn't address that question.**

The notable claim was a quote:

> millions of people in the developing world spend up to 6 hours every day just collecting the water they need to survive.

**The answer didn't determine if that claim was correct.**

At the bottom of the post were a list of questions. Arguably, they should have been edited to keep them focused on the actual claim, but this is how they read when you answered:

> - Are there any populations that spend much of the day just to collect water?

**The answer didn't address that question.**

> - A single village?

**The answer didn't address that question.**

> If yes, what prevents them from moving closer to
>   the water and how long has it been this way?

Notice the "If yes" conditional? **The answer didn't address whether the sentence premise was true.**

All it attempted to answer was the first half of the second part of the final question, which it did purely from a theoretical model and without any evidence, which means it would have been eventually deleted anyway.

I recommend reading our [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users) to better understand what we are looking for in answers.