# Question worded to force ufologists and skeptics to provide the best UFO evidence = downvotes

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Skeptics Stack Exchange post: [Is there definitive proof that general UFO phenomenon is fake or real?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/44733/is-there-definitive-proof-that-general-ufo-phenomenon-is-fake-or-real)

I would like to invoke readers to provide the closest thing to proof instead of the typical skeptics' debunking. Or the extraordinary ufo claims. (unless backed up)

### Question

May, I continue to word my questions that actually forces both sides to consider what is true and look at the evidence (in this case the closet to it) without being downvoted?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Skeptics.SE, Travis. Please have a read of the [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/faq-welcome-to-new-users).

I saw your meta-question before I saw your actual question. The actual question has a number of issues with it. I couldn't see how to simply resolve them, so I put it On Hold, while we work out how to fix them.

- The title meanders from the claim.

  "Proof" isn't a scientific word. You can ask for good, empirical evidence, but that is implied in every question. Every time I see someone ask "Is it A or B?" I wonder if there is a false dichotomy hiding there. So the question title should be "Do UFOs exist?"
- The question is vague.

  The concepts "extra terrestrial", "alien craft visiting earth" and "UFO sighting" are distinct.

  No-one doubts there are (true and fake) sightings of "Unidentified Flying Objects". The leap that some people make is that this is evidence of alien craft visiting the Earth. If your question is about alien craft visiting the Earth, you need to be more specific.

  If your question is more generally whether extra terrestrial exists (whether they come to buzz by the Earth or not), we already have a question on that: [Is there any strong evidence of alien life?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1202/is-there-any-strong-evidence-of-alien-life)

  (Admittedly, it also has a bad title. I should edit.)
- It is too broad, which makes it one-sided.

  You claim to ask both sides to consider what is true, but there is no way of answering this question "No". To do that, an answerer would have to show that every single UFO claim was explicable or unreliable.

  If, instead, you point to a specific claim of a specific UFO sighting there is at least the *possibility* of explaining it (although if no-one could explain it, we would need to be careful that we weren't just [anomaly hunting](https://theness.com/neurologicablog/index.php/anomaly-hunting/).)
- The notability reference you provide isn't the claim you ask about.

  Further to the above, you do provide an example of a UFO sighting claim, but you don't ask about that. Instead, you set up your own standard of evidence (which isn't a reasonable one - there could be alien craft unable to meet your standards.)

Comment: "Do UFOs exist?" is also a dupe: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/765/have-there-been-any-credible-reports-of-unidentified-flying-objects