# Can the About page be improved?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[New user comments](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18586/is-pen-ink-toxic-for-the-skin#comment72189_18586) say, "**this site's on/off-topic definition is kind of confusing compared to other SE sites**", and, "I took the tour".

The "tour" must be a reference to [the About page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/tour) (because the hyperlink to that page from the Help button on the top-of-page banner says, "Tour - Start here for a quick overview of the site").

To what extent can this About page be customized? I guess that,

1. This part can be customized:

   > **Welcome to Skeptics Stack Exchange**
   >
   > (Logo)
   >
   > Skeptics is a question and answer site for applying scientific
   >   skepticism. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange
   >   network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build
   >   a library of detailed answers challenging unreferenced notable claims,
   >   pseudoscience and biased results.
2. The rest cannot be customized (except in choosing the example questions and answers).

Can we improve either of the above?

- Some text to specify what's on- and off-topic
- A hyperlink to the [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2512/2703) answer (and/or other FAQ topics)
- Choose an example question which includes a notable claim (or especially create an example question just for that purpose)

The above page seems to me to suggest you can post any random/unreferenced claims/questions.

Comment: All three of your bullets are *possible*, as - as you note - the intro text, on/off-topic lists and example questions are all customizeable. Just gotta decide what should go there...

Comment: What exactly is the size restriction (e.g. how many lines of text) on the example question? IIRC someone once alleged that that question didn't/couldn't include a notable claim, because there wasn't room for one in that template.

Comment: 400 characters, off the top of my head.

Comment: The first paragraph of the About page of other web sites (e.g. StackOverflow and Bicycles) are equally brief, without an on-topic/off-topic list and without links to their FAQ or Help pages. Are they (really) customizeable?

Comment: Yup. Generally-speaking, less is more. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164778/what-should-we-put-on-our-about-page/164779#164779

Answer (score 1):

*I'm interpreting this question as 'What may we do?' as opposed to 'What should we do?'.*

As described in [What are all the different FAQs and Help pages?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/981/what-are-all-the-different-faqs-and-help-pages/2511#2511), [this intro page is editable](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Your suggestions should follow [the guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164778/what-should-we-put-on-our-about-page/164779#164779). (Hat tip to @Sklivvz)

You could [post your improvement suggestions here](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/948/improving-the-faq). (I think could legitimately start a new meta-question too if you preferred.)