# Improve the About page

Tags: discussion, proposed-faq

Further to [Can the About page be improved?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2569/2703) I suggest adding something like the following content to the page.

---

The purpose of this site is to question whether [notable claims](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2506/2703) are true. In general any question of the following form is on topic:

> [*Reference to notable claim*] says, ["*quote from the notable claim*"]. **Is this claim true?**

The subject of the claim can be almost any topic: science, pseudo-science, advertisements, quotes, etc.

For further details see:

- [FAQ: What are the attributes of a good question?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/882/2703)
- [FAQ: What makes an answer good on Skeptics.SE?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1024/2703)
- [Welcome to New Users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users)

The following are a few examples of some well-phrased questions:

- *Example 1 (to be supplied)*
- *Example 2 (to be supplied)*
- *Example 3 (to be supplied)*

The following are off-topic on this site:

- Questions whose subject is not a notable claim
- Answers which don't include references.

Answer (score 1):

> In general any question of the following form is on topic

I disagree with this blanket statement because it's false, for example:

> The Bible says, "God created the universe". Is this claim true?

Is clearly not on topic here, as any other metaphysical/belief question" "Was Hitler a convinced Catholic?", "Does Al Gore endorse environmentalism for his personal gain?", etc.

Also, we don't *need* any claim source. A claim needs to notable, but that's it: a source may or may not be useful. In fact, in the case of very notable claims, a claim source might be worse because it may not be really representative of the wider claim.

Finally we certainly don't *need* a quote from the claim. Sometimes it's nice, but it's certainly *not* compulsory (or sign of a good question at all).

Some times we might have two claims (claim and counter claim). They might both be notable. Again, it's fine to have a single question.

In other cases, decent notability sources might simply not be available - that's *fine* as long as the claim is notable.

So, asking a question should be allowed with a much broader range of formulations than you imply in your post - it worries me to focus the community to look for a specific formula instead of understanding *why* we need notability and null hypothesis.

Comment: Do you want to leave the About page as it is now? Suggest any addition?

Comment: Rearching how to incorporate this answer, I see that the God topic isn't mentioned in [FAQ: What are the attributes of a good question?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/882/2703) nor in [FAQ: What makes an answer good on Skeptics.SE?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1023/2703). By searching for 'teapot' I found your answer to [What constitutes reasonable evidence for questions with an impossible negation?](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1236/2703) in which you claim that such questions shouldn't be allowed, and ...

Comment: ... your answer to [Do ghosts exist?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/789/2703). Do you think it's worth having a short addition to the About page? Are God questions a big enough problem that they're worth mentioning on the About page? Should my suggestion above be a) Dropped entirely b) Made longer (e.g. to exclude God) c) Made shorter (to rely more on the FAQs and not even try to be definitive in itself)?

Comment: @ChrisW longer answer now

Comment: How do you demonstrate that a claim is notable *without* a source?

Comment: How do you demonstrate what the claim *is* without a quote?

Comment: @Articuno Just picking at random: "Do polygraphs (lie-detectors) work?" is a notable claim, which doesn't need any example to be valid.

Comment: You seem to confuse the need for references in answers for the need of notability in questions. They are not the same thing. We can give people the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Articuno [When argued that topic before](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/2499/2703) the popular opinion (voting) was fairly clear.

Comment: Oh okay, so when is an "off-topic because this is a non-notable claim" close-vote appropriate?

Comment: Also, [FAQ: Must all questions be notable](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/864/faq-must-all-questions-be-notable) says: "*if one person shows up and disputes the claim (leaves a comment, or flags for moderator attention) - then it's the responsibility of the asker (or your friendly neighborhood editor) to dig up a real, verifiable source. After all, if it's actually common knowledge, then there should be some reference to it out there*".

Comment: @Articuno, does it say that every question *must* have a notable reference? Forcing everyone to source their question would be see as downright hostile to new comers and askers. Please avoid doing so! :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz I really try to be polite about it. I have an auto-comment set up that I use when I doubt the notability or specificity of a claim: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18638/hand-washing-dishes-vs-automatic-dishwasher#comment72513_18638

Comment: @Articuno furthermore, asking that an example of the claim be given does not (a) restrict the claim to that example necessarily or (b) imply that the form proposed by Chris is ever required at all

Comment: @Sklivvz How do we know what the claim *is* then? How do we know that the version that the person is asking about is notable if there is no evidence that anyone believes the claim they're challenging?

Comment: [chat] please :-)