# Is asking a question to validate/verify the real world origins of the practice of being a “Soupeur” appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion

First, I hope nobody who is reading this has just eaten…

Okay, I was chatting with some friends and the topic of the “[Soupeur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soupeur)” came up. Apparently this is a word used in France to describe the practice of — and I quote:

> “…a sexual practice involving attraction to other male secretions, specifically bread soaked in urine, or semen.”

Now, as shocking as that sounds, it also sounds like urban legend nonsense… But for the fact that references to the practice exist in literature dating back to the early 20th century in that Wikipedia article but no real world references.

And all references are strictly connected to French culture with no equivalents found in other cultures which is quite odd from a sociological standpoint: As vile as that practice sounds, there should be other references in other cultures, right?

So my question would be:

> ## Is there any real world evidence to prove that the French sexual practice of being “Soupeur” actually exists or has existed?

So would this question be appropriate for posting here?

Comment: The meta nature of this question is doing my head in. If this WASN'T acceptable on the main site, this meta-question would also not be acceptable!

Comment: Unrelated: Titles of the form "Is there any real world evidence to prove that [X] exists?" are regularly edited to "Does [X] exist?. It is not just much simpler, given the rest is implied by the rules, it also more symmetric: Evidence that it *doesn't* exist should be permitted in an answer.

Comment: I was really hoping for something more innocent, like "saucier". The WWW: Taking away childhood innocence since 1991.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date, we haven't yet identified any taboo topics.

[An FAQ answer states](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/faq-what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/892#892)

> The question should be phrased using respectful language.
>
> While there are no taboo topics here, all claims (and especially potentially offensive claims such as claims about race or porn) must be asked about in respectful manners. It is hard to know what people find offensive, but it's a lot easier for a reader to understand if the language of the question is respectful.
>
> Profanities in answers and questions will be removed. They are not allowed here.

I have put potentially offensive photos behind links tagged "NSFW" or similar to allow people to choose whether they wish to view them.